# Jasmine and Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, rxjs

I am trying to test an authentication method I created using TypeScript in my Angular project. I have used a mix of Mockito and Jasmine to create my test cases and mocks, but I believe there should be a better way of approaching this. I'm having an issue to keep track of methods being fired up and what being returned when obseravle is created.

**Method:**

```
public login(username: string, password: string): Observable<TokenResponse> {
    return this.client.authenticate(username, password).pipe(
        tap(tokenResponse => {
            this.storeToken(tokenResponse.access_token, tokenResponse.refresh_token, tokenResponse.expires_in);
            this.keepAlive();
        })
    );
}
```

**Test:**

```
describe('and when `login` is called', () => {
    let response, subject;

    beforeEach(() => {
        subject = new Subject();
        mockito.when(MockedClientClass.authenticate('username', 'password')).thenReturn(subject);
        response = sut.login('username', 'password');
    });

    it('should return an observable', () => {
        expect(response instanceof Observable).toBe(true);
    });

    describe('and when the observable is subscribed to', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            mockito.when(MockedTokenClass.getTokenStorage()).thenReturn(mockedTokenStorageInstance);
            response.subscribe();
            subject.next(false);
        });

        it('save response token into token storage', () => {
            mockito.verify(MockedTokenStorageClass.save(mockito.anyOfClass(TokenEntity))).once();
        });

        describe('and when `isLoggedIn` called', () => {
            it('should show user as logged in when token is stored and valid', () => {
                mockito.when(MockedTokenClass.isValid()).thenReturn(true);
                expect(sut.isLoggedIn()).toBe(true);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: So ... Do you have an error or something ?

Comment: No i don't, I just don't think this is the proper way of testing observables, any suggestion?

Comment: I would suggest you stop using mockito but that's personal preference.

Comment: How would you approach it?

Comment: Without mockito and with custom made mocks and observables.